# Why are numbers being inserted into MongoDB incorrectly?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm working on my first application and ran into something I can't figure out. While making a call to an external REST API I get a response that I parse into JSON, then insert into MongoDB.

When logging the parsed response into console, I'll get expected responses that look like this:

```
{ "userkey": 1265305129852079875, "datakey": 5436379464010906368 }
```

When I look in MongoDB, the data now looks like this, where the numbers rounded up?

```
{ "userkey": 1265305129852079900, "datakey": 5436379464010907000 }
```

After hunting around I can see that these are being inserted as BSON type double, but I'm not entirely sure what this means or how to get my result to save as I see it in the console.

Comment: On the point of insertion, are they being inserted as [**`NumberLong()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#numberlong)?

Comment: The insertion is just the json response directly. After looking at your link it sounds like I need to break the response out and specifically set my keys as NumberLong()